# Make a javascript function workable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, if-statement

Here I have an array `place.reviews` but this array is sometimes empty so I need to write a function that first will check array is empty ot not and if not then to go getting data from array...

SO I try:

```
if (!!place.reviews) for(var i=0;i<place.reviews.length;i++){
  contentStr += '<br>'+ place.reviews[i].text+ '</br>';
}
```

But this code dont work for me?

Is here problem with  `if (!!place.reviews)` or ... ?

Comment: You can try `place.reviews[0]` as condition to if statement.

Comment: Can place.reviews be undefined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because any not null object is "truthy".

Assuming your array might be `undefined` (if it can't there's no point in testing before the loop), you should do

```
if (place.reviews && place.reviews.length)
```

Comment: This will continue if the array is empty tho.

Answer (score 2):

Why check for *emptyness* at all?

```
for(var i=0;i<place.reviews.length;i++)
```

Your for loop-body doesn't execute at all if place.reviews.length is 0.

Comment: +1 because if the array is guaranteed being defined and being an array, then it's the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is not well formed, use this:

```
if (place.reviews.length) 
    for(var i=0;i<place.reviews.length;i++) {
        contentStr += '<br>'+ place.reviews[i].text+ '</br>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (place.reviews.length > 0)
```